# If element present do stuff, if not present skip next

Tags: vba, selenium, automated-tests, web-testing, webautomation

I am bumped in a situation where I need to do something if an element exists, and if that element does not exists I will need to skip to the rest of the code. I have tried several methods but I do not know why it does not work, the code looks logical to me and it worked for similar macros.
Code below:

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until driver.ExecuteScript("document.readystate") <> "complete"

If driver.FindElementByName("x").IsPresent Then
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Completed already" 'And need to skip to next iteration

ElseIf driver.FindElementByName("x") Is Nothing Then
Set cancel= driver.FindElementByName("cancelbutton")
cancel.Click


Set myVar= Item.Offset(0, 1)
Set radiobtn = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='" & myVar & "']")    
radiobtn.Click

Set cancelSelected = driver.FindElementByName("submitCancel")
cancelSelected.Click
driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Canceled"
driver.Refresh
driver.Wait 1000
End If
```

I have also tried the situation where if the element X is present, then find other element

```
If driver.FindElementByName("x").IsPresent Then
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Completed already"

ElseIf driver.FindElementByName("Y").IsPresent Then
Set cancel= driver.FindElementByName("cancelbutton")
cancel.Click


Set myVar= Item.Offset(0, 1)
Set radiobtn = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='" & myVar & "']")
radiobtn.Click

Set cancelSelected = driver.FindElementByName("submitCancel")
cancelSelected.Click
driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Canceled"
driver.Refresh
driver.Wait 1000
End If
```

When element X is present on the page element Y is not, and vice versa. I have also tried `.count > 0` but it still does not work. Could anyone help me with a solution or give me some tips and trick?

Comment: Is there an url we can use to make this a reproducible problem please?

Comment: And of course, suitable x,y values for the scenario please

Comment: Unfortunately even if I share an URL you cannot see it because it is business related and secured by VPN and 2factor authenticators..

Comment: Please provide more detail then on what you tried and in each case what the exact result was including any error messages in full. Include an explicit wait times you have added if used and relevant to the error messages,

Comment: It's exactly as described. There is a code that waits until all of the elements are loaded on the page `Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until driver.ExecuteScript("document.readystate") <> "complete"`. Also Element X does not exist on every form. What I tried to do is to give a condition, If element X is present, do stuff, else if not present, do something else. the error received is NoSuchElementError Name=x.

Comment: readystate will not wait until all elements are loaded. It is less reliable than the inbuilt implicit webdriver waits. If an error is thrown why not have an error handling section which deals with that scenario then have a resume next to take you back? So long as you have an exit sub before the error handler, and an appropriate err.Number test in the err handler might be ok i.e. use the error, or lack thereof, to branch your code. Remember to reset error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I bought a course on Udemy and found the answer myself. There are several ways to find if an element is present and what to do next if it is or not present. Funny, the solution is so simple that I'm embarrassed I missed it.

First `Dim By AS New By`
Then add a split second of wait before and after the if clause:

```
driver.Wait 500
If driver.IsElementPresent(By.Name("uncompleteButton__")) Then
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Can't do stuff, go to next iteration."
Else
Set cancelitemsbtn = driver.FindElementByName("cancelButton")
cancelitemsbtn.Click
Item.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Can do stuff"
driver.Wait 500
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use not driver.findelement but driver.findelements(By.whatever).size()>0  I hope it works with vbs, it works with Java 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in VBA we can write driver.find both ways, i have tried it this way before as well, but it does not work.

Comment: Maybe you need some time to wait for that element if that is the case, you can use smart waits like e.g 
WebDriverWait w1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 8);
  w1.until(ExpectedConditions.or(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("submit_btn")),
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.visible-desktop a.hosted-payment-btn.btn-primary"))));

And after that use the size thing.